# Determining the domain of convergence of a function

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

For

$$f_n(x)=n\cdot \sin\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$$

How do I determine for what values of x this series converge? (like $[a,b]$ or $(a,b]$...)

thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the known limit
$$ \lim_{u \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin{u}}{u} = 1$$
For each $x$, try to find an appropriate substitution for $u$ in terms of $x,n$.

Comment: okay I got that.. $\frac{sin(u)}{u}=usin(\frac{1}{u})$ for $u=1/u$.. how do i determine the values for which the series converge?

Comment: I don't think you've quite got it yet. Try writing $u$ in terms of $x,n$. You want to the turn the known limit into the limit you're trying to compute. Also, you don't have a series.